# TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars - Earth Observation

Tags: python, numpy

I'm attempting to create a script that will take a .GTiff file as an argument input and then extract some information out of the file to create a stats.txt file that will give me the classID, fractional coverage and total number of pixels of that classID.

Thus far I believe I have everything I need but I keep running into the same error and my attempts to rectify the error haven't proven to be very fruitful.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import calendar
import os

import gdal
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import mode

from IPython import embed

GDAL2NUMPY = {  gdal.GDT_Byte      :   np.uint8,
                gdal.GDT_UInt16    :   np.uint16,
                gdal.GDT_Int16     :   np.int16,
                gdal.GDT_UInt32    :   np.uint32,
                gdal.GDT_Int32     :   np.int32,
                gdal.GDT_Float32   :   np.float32,
                gdal.GDT_Float64   :   np.float64,
                gdal.GDT_CInt16    :   np.complex64,
                gdal.GDT_CInt32    :   np.complex64,
                gdal.GDT_CFloat32  :   np.complex64,
                gdal.GDT_CFloat64  :   np.complex128
              }


#Open the original training data .tif map file.

fname = sys.argv[1]
lc_dataset = gdal.Open(fname)
lc = lc_dataset.ReadAsArray()
lc = np.array(lc)

#Calculating total number of pixels with a valid Land Cover ID.

fill_value = 0
number_of_pixels = np.where(lc != fill_value)[0].shape[0]

#Get the number of classes and corresponding IDs.

lc_classes = np.unique(lc)

#Split each class into its contituante pixel and write result to file.

for classID in range(1, lc_classes):
    lc_class_pixels = np.where(lc == classID)[0].shape[0]
    FractionalCover = lc_class_pixels/number_of_pixels
    f.write(classID, FractionalCoverage, lc_class_pixels)

f.close()
```

When I run this, it chuck up the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "GeneratingLCstats.py", line 45, in <module>
    for classID in range(1, lc_classes):
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

I've attempted a few changes as I'm sure the error is related to numpy data and native python data interactions, but converting all my arrays to numpy arrays and attempting to reformat the code has proved in vain as the same error persists.

If anyone can suggest a fix that would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the function `lc_classes = np.unique(lc)` returns an array. When you try to write the for loop as

`for classID in range(1, lc_classes)`

Here, lc_classes is an array and trying to give it as a bound for the `range` causes the error. If you want to iterate over the length of the array, you can modify the code to :

`for classID in range(1, len(lc_classes))`